# C# Asp.Net - Json AppendFormat is giving back an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, syntax-error, amcharts

I am currently working on a program which should put the information from the sql database in a **json format** so it can be used for **amCharts**. Im getting an **System.Format.Exception** Error which i wasnt able to fix it. Im still learning to use C# Asp.Net.
Here is my code:

```
// Get the connection string
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMMonitor_SQL"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            // Establish the connection with the database
            conn.Open();

            // Construct and execute SQL query which would return the total amount for each year
            SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(chartSQL, conn);

            // Begin iterating through the result set
            SqlDataReader rst = query.ExecuteReader();

while (rst.Read())
{
   jsonStr.AppendFormat("{\"label\": \"{0}\", \"value\": \"{1}\"}", @rst[0].ToString(), @rst[1].ToString());

}
```

The output should look like this:

```
"data": [{
    "label": "label1",
    "value": 501
  }, {
    "label": "label2",
    "value": 301
  }, {
    "label": "label3",
    "value": 128
  }]
```

Comment: This is hard to look at. Why not serialize a BL object with Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1):

Please use a tool specially designed to create JSON output, like [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class MyService
{
    private void Example()
    {
        using (var command = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            using (var rst = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                do
                {
                    var columns = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rst.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        columns.Add(rst.GetName(i));
                    }

                    while (rst.Read())
                    {
                        // use JObject to generate the JSON on the fly
                        var jsonObject = new JObject();

                        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string name = columns[i];
                            object value = rst.GetValue(i);
                            JToken jsonValue = JToken.FromObject(value);
                            jsonObject.Add(name, jsonValue);
                        }

                        // serialize the JObject to JSON output
                        string asJsonString = jsonObject.ToString();
                    }
                } while (rst.NextResult());
            }
        }
    }
}
```